# Householder Transformation question

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that for Householder Transformation $H= I -2\frac{vv^\top}{v^\top v}$ and $v \neq 0$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}^n$ and is orthogonal.

> Find vector $u$ such that, $Hu =u$
>
> Find vector $w$ such that $Hw=-w$

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far? Can you relate the vectors $u$ and $w$ to $v$?

Comment: @TheoBendit i tried to sub H for the above formula but didn't know how to get the non-trivial solution. I know u can be something like [-1 0 0] and w can be [1 0 0] but I dont know how to get that.

Comment: What does it mean for a single vector ($v$) to be orthogonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part, note  that $$Hv=\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)v=v-2\frac{vv^Tv}{v^Tv}=v-2v=-v$$

For the first part, take some vector $w$ orthogonal to $v$, i.e. $v^Tw=0$.  Now
$$Hw=\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)w=w-2\frac{vv^Tw}{v^Tv}=w-2\frac{v0}{v^Tv}=w-0=w$$

You can learn about Householder transformations (and matrices) on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).  For intuition, multiplication by $H$ reflects in the hyperplane that is normal to vector $v$.  Hence, all vectors in that hyperplane are fixed, while all vectors parallel to $v$ are multiplied by $-1$.  This is a very useful operation, allowing reflection in just one axis.